# How to get or edit exif for video in iOS

Tags: ios, video, exif

I want to edit exif for a video.

I shoot video with a custom camera.But this video lacks exif information. I searched the Internet for a long time，not found any way.
The PHAsset doesn't OK，because I don't need save the video in Photo album。
 Who can help me ,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/finding_metadata_values?language=objc) to get metadata.
To work with metadata you will use AVMetadataItem items.
To load metadata use next example:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "audio", withExtension: "m4a")!
let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
let formatsKey = "availableMetadataFormats"

asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [formatsKey]) {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: formatsKey, error: &error)
    if status == .loaded {
        for format in asset.availableMetadataFormats {
            let metadata = asset.metadata(forFormat: format)
            // process format-specific metadata collection
        }
    }
}
```